# Showing cannot open file

Tags: android, pdf, file-io

This is my code to download and then open the file from the sdcard.

But after downloading the file, when I click on the file to open it, it shows a Toast message: `cannot open file`

Please tell me where is the error.

```
package com.pdf;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PdffileActivity extends Activity 
{
   WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

      String pdf = "http://officeofthemufti.sg/MaulidBooklet.pdf";
      webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
      setContentView(webview);

      File file=new File("/sdcard/MaulidBooklet.pdf");

      if (file.exists())
      {
         Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);

        try
        {
           startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
           Toast.makeText(PdffileActivity.this,
                          "No Application Available to View PDF",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a pdf reader installed?

Comment: print your stack trace in the `catch` clause and you'll know (or post the stack trace if it's still not clear)

Comment: @ Michał K;still not clear to me tell me in steps what i have to do..

Comment: @Ovidiu Latcu:Dear i want to open it pro grammatically...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it programatically as you say, and  assuming it has been downloaded into the standard 'download' directory then you can change your declaration and instantiation of the new file to the following:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)  + "/MaulidBooklet.pdf");
```

This does assume you are using Android 2.2 or newer.

You can check the file is actually being downloaded into this directory by using DDMS to browse the 'Download' directory on your device.